# Having trouble with my switch statement... are there any limitations for it?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
while(5){
    printf("\n1-Insert_at_end\n2-search_value\n3-Display_list\n4-delete_entire_list\n");
    printf("\n Your option\t");
    scanf("%d\n",&o);
    switch(o){
        case 1:
            insertion_at_end();
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("element to search\n");
            scanf("%d\n",&a);
            search_value(a);
            break;
        case 3:
            display_list();
            break;
        case 4:
            delete_entire_list();
            break;
        default:
            printf("inavalid option\n");
            break;

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? And what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `while (5)` is usually written as `while (1)` or `for (;;)`

Answer (score 2):

Your `scanf` has an extra whitespace

```
scanf("%d\n",&o);
//     ^^   <== read optional whitespace followed by digits
//       ^^ <== read whitespace
```

This scanf will stop only when it sees something that is not whitespace. For example entering <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> will make the `%d` ignore the first two spaces the use the `4` and the `2` to assign to `o`, then scanf will ignore the two ENTERS and stop when it gets to the `x` which remains in the input buffer.

You want simply

```
if (scanf("%d", &o) != 1) /* error */;
```

Comment: very thanks to you sir. after removing \n i am getting correct